# how to construct table in jQuery using for loop and .append() method

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to create a table using .append() method, as shown in below:

```js
$('#myTable').append("<tr><td><input type='radio' class='with-gap' id='primary0' name='radioBtn' value='0'/><label for='primary0'></label></td><td><input type='checkbox' name='checkgroup' id='checkedBox0' class='filled-in' value='0'><label for='checkedBox0'></label></td></tr>");
$('#myTable').append("<tr><td><input type='radio' class='with-gap' id='primary1' name='radioBtn' value='1'/><label for='primary1'></label></td><td><input type='checkbox' name='checkgroup' id='checkedBox1' class='filled-in' value='1'><label for='checkedBox1'></label></td></tr>");
$('#myTable').append("<tr><td><input type='radio' class='with-gap' id='primary2' name='radioBtn' value='2'/><label for='primary2'></label></td><td><input type='checkbox' name='checkgroup' id='checkedBox2' class='filled-in' value='2'><label for='checkedBox2'></label></td></tr>");
$('#myTable').append("<tr><td><input type='radio' class='with-gap' id='primary3' name='radioBtn' value='3'/><label for='primary3'></label></td><td><input type='checkbox' name='checkgroup' id='checkedBox3' class='filled-in' value='3'><label for='checkedBox3'></label></td></tr>");
$('#myTable').append("<tr><td><input type='radio' class='with-gap' id='primary4' name='radioBtn' value='4'/><label for='primary4'></label></td><td><input type='checkbox' name='checkgroup' id='checkedBox4' class='filled-in' value='4'><label for='checkedBox4'></label></td></tr>");
$('#myTable').append("<tr><td><input type='radio' class='with-gap' id='primary5' name='radioBtn' value='5'/><label for='primary5'></label></td><td><input type='checkbox' name='checkgroup' id='checkedBox5' class='filled-in' value='5'><label for='checkedBox5'></label></td></tr>");
$('#myTable').append("<tr><td><input type='radio' class='with-gap' id='primary6' name='radioBtn' value='6'/><label for='primary6'></label></td><td><input type='checkbox' name='checkgroup' id='checkedBox6' class='filled-in' value='6'><label for='checkedBox6'></label></td>></tr>");
$('#myTable').append("<tr><td><input type='radio' class='with-gap' id='primary7' name='radioBtn' value='7'/><label for='primary7'></label></td><td><input type='checkbox' name='checkgroup' id='checkedBox7' class='filled-in' value='7'><label for='checkedBox7'></label></td></tr>");
$('#myTable').append("<tr><td><input type='radio' class='with-gap' id='primary8' name='radioBtn' value='8'/><label for='primary8'></label></td><td><input type='checkbox' name='checkgroup' id='checkedBox8' class='filled-in' value='8'><label for='checkedBox8'></label></td></tr>");
$('#myTable').append("<tr><td><input type='radio' class='with-gap' id='primary9' name='radioBtn' value='9'/><label for='primary9'></label></td><td><input type='checkbox' name='checkgroup' id='checkedBox9' class='filled-in' value='9'><label for='checkedBox9'></label></td></tr>");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="striped" id="myTable" >
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Primary</th>
      <th>Tag / Untag</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
</table>
```

Now my question is how to append my table in a more simply way, such as using for loop in jQuery?
By the way, one more requirement is to construct the table by .append() method.

Comment: Is this table need to be rendered from some data source? You can use each function for doing the same task.

Comment: Jquery For Loop?? Its javascript for loop.. Jquery is just a wrapper on top of javascript

Comment: you have data for table? or you have a pattern for generated table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i try to make your code more simple

avoid using append multiple time, you just need one time.

try this

```js
var html = "";
for(i=0;i<10;i++){
  html += "<tr><td><input type='radio' class='with-gap' id='primary"+i+"' name='radioBtn' value='"+i+"'/><label for='primary"+i+"'></label></td><td><input type='checkbox' name='checkgroup' id='checkedBox"+i+"' class='filled-in' value='"+i+"'><label for='checkedBox"+i+"'></label></td></tr>";
}

$("#myTable").append(html);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="striped" id="myTable" >
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Primary</th>
      <th>Tag / Untag</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Using for loop you can achieve it

```js
for(i=0;i<=9;i++){
  $('#myTable').append("<tr><td><input type='radio' class='with-gap' id='primary"+i+"' name='radioBtn' value='"+i+"'/><label for='primary"+i+"'></label></td><td><input type='checkbox' name='checkgroup' id='checkedBox0' class='filled-in' value='"+i+"'><label for='checkedBox"+i+"'></label></td></tr>");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="striped" id="myTable" >
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Primary</th>
      <th>Tag / Untag</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a row for each item in a loop and append it to a table:

```js
var target = $('#test');
var rows = '';
for(var i=0;i<10;i++) {
  rows += '<tr><td>' + i + '</td><td>cell_' + i + '</td></tr>';
}
var tbl = $('<table><tbody>' + rows + '</tbody></table');
target.append(tbl);
```

```css
#test td {
  border: 1px solid #d8d8d8;
  padding:5px 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="test"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a boucle for like this :

```js
function appendTableRow(nbRow)
{
        var i = 0;
        for(i = 0; i < nbRow; i++)
        {
            $('#myTable').append("<tr><td><input type='radio' class='with-gap' id='primary" + i + "' name='radioBtn' value='"+ i +"'/><label for='primary" + i + "'></label></td><td><input type='checkbox' name='checkgroup' id='checkedBox" + i + "' class='filled-in' value='"+i+"'><label for='checkedBox"+i+"></label></td></tr>");
        }
}

appendTableRow(10);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="striped">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Primary</th>
      <th>Tag / Untag</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="myTable">
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

For loop is a good option with a method call. This can be achieved as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 function createTable(numrows){
   for(i=0;i<=numrows;i++){
      $('#myTable').append("<tr><td><input type='radio' class='with-gap' id='primary"+i+"' name='radioBtn' value='"+i+"'/><label for='primary"+i+"'></label></td><td><input type='checkbox' name='checkgroup' id='checkedBox0' class='filled-in' value='"+i+"'><label for='checkedBox"+i+"'></label></td></tr>");
   }
 }
</script>
```

```
 <table class="striped" id="myTable" >
  <thead>
  <tr>
    <th>Primary</th>
    <th>Tag / Untag</th>
  </tr>
  </thead>
 </table>
 <script type="text/javascript>createTable(9);</script>
```